# Basis of column space equivalence to transpose row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If I find a basis for the column space of A, will that basis also be a basis for the column space of col(A transpose) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general. First, if $A$ is not a square matrix then the column space and the row space live in vector spaces of different dimension. But even if it is a square matrix, then this claim is not true. For example 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
has column space spaned by $\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)$ while $A^T$ has column space spanned by $\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)$.
While these spaces are not the same, they do have the same dimension, and this is always true.